# Vector Bearing Application

Tags: trigonometry

This time i am presenting a problem i abolsutely have no clue on how to do... its suppose to be on of our test review for our tomorow test, so i atleast need a clue on how to do this!

A Plane's heading is $160 ^\circ$ and its air speed is $350mph$. If a west wind is blowing at 20mph, what are the planes ground speed and true course..

Since i obviously cant draw a diagram of this, and i have to show what i tried. The only representation i have left is a picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful:  the speed of the airplane is $350~\text{mph}$ in the text and $250~\text{mph}$ in your diagram.

I use $350~\text{mph}$ in the diagram below.  Adjust as appropriate.

[image: airplane_heading]

In the diagram, the vector $\overrightarrow{AC}$ represents the airplane's heading, the vector $\overrightarrow{CB}$ represents the wind, and the vector $\overrightarrow{AB}$ represents the true course of the airplane.  The  magnitude of $\overrightarrow{AB}$ is the ground speed of the airplane.

That said, notice that $\overleftrightarrow{WE} \parallel \overrightarrow{CB}$ and that the angle ($\angle ACB$) between the airplane's heading and the direction of the wind is the alternate interior angle of the $70^\circ$ angle, so you know the lengths of two sides of $\triangle ABC$ and the measures of the angle between them, which allows you to use the Law of Cosines to find the airplane's ground speed.  Once you have figured that out, you can use the Law of Sines to determine the measure of $\angle BAC$, then add that to $160^\circ$ to find the airplane's true course.

Comment: Thankyou! I got that in class. Also did great on Test! Again Thankyou!!